# Active sessions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, session

How can I create active sessions in oracle( so that it keeps on running (foreground or background))?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what this session is going to be doing?

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to know exactly what you're looking for, but I suggest you check out DBMS_SCHEDULER.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm

It will allow you to set up a job that would be able to restart when it ends or errors.  So in effect, it will just keep running in the background on your DB.

---

This is untested (don't have access to a DB at the mo), but should get you close:

```
 BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
     job_name        => 'your-job-name',
     job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
     job_action      => 'BEGIN your_job_procedure(); END;',
     start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
     repeat_interval => 'systimestamp',
     end_date        => NULL,
     enabled         => TRUE,
     comments        => 'Comment');
 END;
 /
```